# create new column from divided columns over iteration

Tags: pandas, loops

I am working with the following code:

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dothemathonthatone/maps/master/fertility.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)

year    regional_schlüssel  Aus15   Deu15   Aus16   Deu16   Aus17   Deu17   Aus18   Deu18   ...     aus36   aus37   aus38   aus39   aus40   aus41   aus42   aus43   aus44   aus45
0   2000    5111000     0   4   8   25  20  45  56  89  ...     935     862     746     732     792     660     687     663     623     722
1   2000    5113000     1   1   4   14  13  33  19  48  ...     614     602     498     461     521     470     393     411     397     400
2   2000    5114000     0   11  0   5   2   13  7   20  ...     317     278     265     235     259     228     204     173     213     192
3   2000    5116000     0   2   2   7   3   28  13  26  ...     264     217     206     207     197     177     171     146     181     169
4   2000    5117000     0   0   3   1   2   4   4   7   ...     135     129     118     116     128     148     89  110     124     83
```

I would like to create a new set of columns `fertility_deu15`, `...`, `fertility_deu45` and `fertility_aus15`, `...`, `fertility_aus45` such that `aus15` `/` `Aus15` = `fertiltiy_aus15`   and `deu15`/ `Deu15` = `fertility_deu15` for each `ausi` and `Ausj where j == i \n [15-45]` and `deui:Deuj where j == i \n [15-45]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is up with that data but we need to fix it to make it numeric.  I'll end up doing that while filtering

```
numerator = df.filter(regex='^[a-z]+\d+$')                   # Lower case ones
numerator = numerator.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')  # Fix numbers

denominator = df.filter(regex='^[A-Z][a-z]+\d+$').rename(columns=str.lower)
denominator = denominator.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

numerator.div(denominator).add_prefix('fertility_')
```

Comment: thank you, this works; only that the identifier columns `year` and `regional_schlüssel` are no longer part of the df. Can I merge `year` and `regional_schlüssel` to `numerator` along the index ?

Comment: yes, just do `df[['year', 'regional_schlüssel']].join(numerator.div(denominator).add_prefix('fertility_'))`

Comment: @ piRsquaired: thank you again for the solution. I have since made some changes to the df (grouped and summed age groups and changed the names of columns from, e.g., Aus15 to Aus15_20. I would like to do the same but am having a difficult time understanding the syntax. that you used on the first and third lines. Can you clear that up for me so that I can adjust the code to fit my new df? Thank you.